# Why some sites don't have any extension on endpoints?

Tags: web-applications, endpoint

Usually I have seen sites serve pages this way. `<domain>/<something>/<something2.php>` looking at the last part we can say its a php page or in other words the server side lang used was php. Same goes for `<domain>/<something>/<something2.aspx>`

But what actually happens when its in this format (without any extension) `<domain>/<something>/<something2>` why there is no extension?

Answer (score 0):

URLs that a web server responds to don't have to have an extension.

The simplest example of this is when you visit `https://stackoverflow.com/` (i.e. the home page. There's no extension there, but there is a response coming back). In a Windows/IIS world this is handled by the concept of a [Default Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/defaultdocument/) where the web server is configured to return a certain page if none is specified in the address requested.

One example of a framework that can use URLs that don't have extensions is ASP.NET. Take a look at the learn.microsoft.com page that describes [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0) and how it does this.

There could also be a web server component (like IIS URL Rewrite) that's taking URLs that the user is providing like `/products/1320` and *rewriting* it so that the actual URL that's processed is `/products.aspx?productId=1320`.